# reserve one core for a special task / process

Tags: linux, scheduling, arm64

For diagnostics I want to let an application on a core that is only reserved for it. I do have a CPU with 4 cores (imx8) - so this is an embedded device - not full blown system.
So I did the isolcpus=0,1,2 bootparam and I could see that pid=1 is running only on 0..2, not 3. That is the case for many, but not for all processes. Some of the processes seems not to care about that. I also can't isolate them with taskset.
How can I make sure that this core3 is really not occupied by anything else?

Comment: there's no distinction between your imx8 and a XEON server from a point of being a "full-blown system".

Comment: which processes are these? How do you observe that?

Comment: with taskset you can see the cores a process can use

Comment: yes, but which processes actually do use the one core you would like to reserve? That might give a hint to what's going on here.

Comment: set isolcpus=2,3

Comment: `root@imx8mp-sp:/opt# taskset -cp 1  
pid 1's current affinity list: 0,1  
root@imx8mp-sp:/opt# taskset -cp 2  
pid 2's current affinity list: 0-3  
root@imx8mp-sp:/opt# taskset -cp 3  
pid 3's current affinity list: 0-3 ` 

    PID USER       VSZ STAT COMMAND
    1 root      2216 S    init [5]
    2 root         0 SW   [kthreadd]
    3 root         0 IW<  [rcu_gp]
    4 root         0 IW<  [rcu_par_gp]